# Slow dns lookup in any browser

Tags: windows-8, firefox, dns

For example in a Firefox when I'm opening any website that I didn't visit for last 3-5 minutes it takes like 10 seconds to load the websites.

In the upper FireFox tab I see this for ten or more seconds:

[image]

Only then a web page is starting to load. I am using Kaspersky Internet Security 2013 and added FireFox and Chrome to a trusted applications. Also tried with completely turned off Kaspersky Internet Security 2013 - no success. When I ping a website from a CMD it has no issues.

Tried from a different laptop with windows 7 no issues at all, so I guess its all about the windows 8 computer. I have tried using the Google DNS - same issue persists. My other computer (laptop) is a Windows 7 laptop and has no problem.

My computer (the one with the problem) is free of virus / malware. When I play World Of WarCraft I don't get any packet loss; it's stable.

My Hosts file is as it should be. Disabling DNS caching service didn't help.

I get 30mb/s download and 30mb/s upload speed. The issue continues if I load a website by domain name or by IP address.

Comment: Trying IE now. I already tried disabling DNS caching service - didn't helped.

Comment: You're not using a SOCKS proxy are you?

Comment: Do you have any P2P software installed? Do you have Bonjour installed?

Comment: @Heihachi At a real shot in the dark, disable any power management settings/plans you have and try again. Go to -> Control Panel/Network and Internet/Network and Sharing center/Ethernet/properties/configure/advanced. Scroll down to -> Energy Efficient Ethernet, Flow Control and Green Ethernet. Disable all three. And another idea - does this occur with all plugins/add ons disabled

Comment: Boot to safe mode and try browsing.  Do you still experience the same slowness?

Comment: Try opendns and see if that helps.

Comment: Switching DNS provider doesn't work. Interestingly, the problem got temporarily solved when I disabled my wireless connection, and I connected using my NIC. However, then I installed Cisco VPN client, and DNS resolution is slow again.

Answer (score -1):

i fixed that using:

`ipconfig /flushdns`